# CRLF (\r\n) shows in email when there is a line break

Tags: php, email

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here. In the emails, `\r\n` keeps showing every time there is a line break. How can I modify the code to fix it?

```
public function sendSupportEmail($email, $name, $comments)
{
    // Wait until Google Apps are configured to accept from this domain
    //$to = "test@mail.com";
    $to = "test@mail.com.com";
    $subject = "Support: Support Inquiry";

    // Headers
    // To send HTML mail, you can set the Content-type header.
    $autoHeaders  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $autoHeaders .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-88591\r\n";
    $autoHeaders .= "From: Web Bot";
    $autoHeaders .= "<webbot@mail.com>\r\n";
    $autoHeaders .= "Reply-To: webbot@mail.com\r\n";
    $autoHeaders .= "Return-Path: webbot@mail.com\r\n";
    $autoHeaders .= "X-Mailer: PHP 5.x\r\n";

    // Print the local date
    $date = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('America/Denver'));
    $datePrint = $date->format('F j, Y, g:i a');

    // Create Text Based Message Below
    $message = "<h3>Support Inquiry sent on {$datePrint}</h3>";
    $message .= "<b>Name:</b><br>{$name}<br><br>";
    $message .= "<b>Email:</b><br><a href='mailto:{$email}'>{$name}</a><br><br>";
    $message .= "<b>Comments:</b><p>{$comments}</p>";

    // Send them the E-Mail
    return mail($to, $subject, $message, $autoHeaders);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean in the body of the mail? Could they be inside `$comments`?

Comment: If `$comments` is coming from a web form `<textarea>`, that's probably where they are coming from.

Comment: @Danny_ds Yes, it is in the body of the actual email. Every time I send a test email with a line break, \r\n is displayed.

Comment: They are probably coming from inside your $comments then. You should replace them with <br> as @st. suggested in his answer.

Comment: what you need is `nl2br()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php @cratto and used against the textarea input (or other inputs/variables) wherever you are using it. I.e.: `$comments = nl2br($comments);` that ought to do the trick.

Comment: But I do not see where you are defining that `$comments` variable anywhere in your question or any others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ideal function to use here would be PHP's `nl2br()` function.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

and used against the textarea input (or other inputs/variables) wherever you are using it. This has been established in comments that that is what you are using for the comments form element.

I.e.: and assuming that your form element is named "comments" and using a POST method for it, since we don't know what that is, or where `$comments` has been assigned as. That wasn't in your question, therefore I am submitting the following as a possible solution.

```
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$comments = nl2br($comments);
```

Or, all in one go:

```
$comments = nl2br($_POST['comments']);
```

- Modify respectively if needed.

Comment: adding $comments = nl2br($_POST['comments']); fixed my issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

As you are sending HTML emails, You need to replace \r\n with < br >'s in email body.

Before returning mail, you should use str_replace function of php as follows.

```
.........
.........
$message .= "<b>Comments:</b><p>{$comments}</p>";
$message = str_replace("\r\n", "<br>", $message); 
// Send them the E-Mail
return mail($to, $subject, $message, $autoHeaders);
```

Comment: I added $message = str_replace("\r\n", "<br>", $message);  as you recommended and still had the same issue. Was there something else I needed to edit in the code? Thanks

Comment: Can you share the email you've received?